# Java - Is the problem that is happening to me because of the cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I currently have a java project with spring boot web and maven. In this project I call an Api Rest that brings me a value from the database, when I update the value in the database and consume again the Api returns the same value of the first Request and not the updated one. The problem is not the Api, because when I call it in the postam it brings me the corresponding value of the Api.

Request Java:

```
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().cache(null).addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .build();
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, strBody);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(prop.getProperty("urlAPI"))
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache")
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token)
                .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

For example:

In the database the value is 60000.

1-I call the API and it brings me the 60000

2-I update the value in the database and leave it at 70000

3-I call the Api again and it brings me the updated value that is the 70000

If I do this same exercise from the java project, it keeps bringing me the 60,000, instead of the 70,000.

Now in the Intellij Idea console it does not show me any error when making the request.

[image: Valor en Base de datos]

Comment: There's not enough information here for someone to help. You haven't shown how you update, how the API you're invoking is defined, how you re-fetch the value, etc.  To help we really need to see a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for the advice c:, I don't know if that's enough information?